# Handling events from dynamic controls NOT added on Page_Load?

Tags: asp.net, postback, page-lifecycle, dynamic-controls

I've read a few articles on here and the web that have informed me that I cannot simply add a new control dynamically to the page, wire it to a handler, and expect it to work.

The solution given each time is that the dynamic controls need to be added to the page on Init each time.

My problem is, my controls are NOT added to the page on init, they are added after ANOTHER postback.

the workflow is this:

1. Page Loads
2. User fills in a textbox, clicks a button
3. Page Posts back, creating dynamic link controls in the button_click event based on the input
4. User clicks one of those link controls to proceed to the next step.

so if this is the behavior I need to support, is there any way to do this? It has to happen in the button_click of step 2, because the dynamic controls are based on the input the user puts in step 2.

have I painted myself into a corner here? how else could I handle such a workflow?

Comment: If your workflow involves "steps", look into the ASP.Net Wizard Control.

Comment: this is great advice, I thought of this initially but wanted to just do it as quickly as possible, and go back and look at using the wizard. this might just do the trick, thanks, will report back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you dynamically create a link button, set a flag in your page's view state. On postback, re-create the link button if the flag is set in view state. Here's a demo:

Markup:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="button1" OnClick="button_Click" Text="Create button A" CommandArgument="A" />
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="button2" OnClick="button_Click" Text="Create button B" CommandArgument="B" />
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="placeHolder"></asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Code-behind:

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private bool LinkButtonCreated
    {
        get { return ((bool?)this.ViewState["LinkButtonCreated"]).GetValueOrDefault(); }
        set { this.ViewState["LinkButtonCreated"] = value; }
    }

    private string LinkButtonCommandArgument
    {
        get { return (string)this.ViewState["LinkButtonCommandArgument"]; }
        set { this.ViewState["LinkButtonCommandArgument"] = value; }
    }

    protected override void LoadViewState(object savedState)
    {
        base.LoadViewState(savedState);
        if (this.LinkButtonCreated)
            this.CreateLinkButton(this.LinkButtonCommandArgument);
    }

    protected void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.LinkButtonCreated)
        {
            string commandArgument = ((Button)sender).CommandArgument;
            this.LinkButtonCreated = true;
            this.LinkButtonCommandArgument = commandArgument;
            this.CreateLinkButton(commandArgument);
        }
    }

    private void CreateLinkButton(string commandArgument)
    {
        LinkButton linkButton =
            new LinkButton
            {
                ID = "linkButton",
                Text = "Click me",
                CommandArgument = commandArgument,
            };
        linkButton.Click += this.linkButton_Click;
        this.placeHolder.Controls.Add(linkButton);
    }

    private void linkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton linkButton = (LinkButton)sender;
        linkButton.Text = "I was clicked! Argument: " + linkButton.CommandArgument;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you kindly, this looks promising, but how do I recreate the linkbuttons based on the input when the button is clicked? I need to pass a value to the link button for the command argument, how do I handle that when I recreate the button?

Comment: Use view state to save anything else you need to re-create the link button, like the command argument. See my updated answer for an example.

Comment: I tried setting it up based on your example, but the LoadViewState is not firing. I should mention, this is in a usercontrol not a page (not sure if that matters). but I put a breakpoint in LoadViewState and it never fires... even on postback

Comment: I moved the code to a user control and it still works; LoadViewState gets called on each postback (it won't get called on the initial request). Make sure there aren't any `EnableViewState="False"` attributes on the page or user control. Also, is your user control, or any other control (other than the link button), dynamically created?

Comment: Actually, LoadViewState should get called only on each postback AFTER the link button gets created.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work. I tried using Session instead of ViewState, and this APPEARS to work. It rebuilds the controls on postback, which is a step forward. however it still doesn't fire the command. any chance this will work? what would I need to change to get the events to fire on postback?

Comment: OKAY! that did it! turns out I was using an invalid character in the ID. it still wouldn't work with viewstate but using session seems to have done the trick, THANK YOU FOR YOUR HELP!

Comment: You're welcome. If session works, great, but I personally would prefer to get it working with view state.

Comment: I'll try to go back and figure it out someday after I get this whole thing done :D thanks again!